# Replacing sequences of space-delimited numbers in huge input with awk

Tags: awk

How can I replace sequences of space-delimited numbers when those sequences span multiple lines and the input is too big to fit in RAM.

###### A sample input would be:

<sub>**edit:** I re-worked the sample input and input parameters for introducing border cases (excluding ones that have to do with the length of the matched sequence or replacement priorities)</sub>

```
   3  12  3   4
   0   6   7  10
   8   9  12   3
   4   6   7  8
  10  6   6   7
  9 199  10  11
  11
```

<sup>**note:** the number of fields per line is homogeneous but not known in advance; the last line might contain less fields</sup>

From that input I would like to:

- replace `3` `4` with `&`
- replace `6` `7` `8` with `9 9`
- replace `6` `7` `9` with `8 8`
- replace `7` `10` with `11 12`
- replace `0` with nothing
- replace `10` with `13 10`
- replace `8` `9` `12` `3` `5` with `#`

The expected output would have one number or replacement per line:

```
3
12
&

6
11 12
8
9
12
&
9 9
13 10
6
8 8
199
13 10
11
11
```

I'm trying to do the task with `awk` but I'm having a hard time implementing a dynamic state machine with a pseudo B-Tree:

```bash
tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' < input.txt |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i += 2) {
            n = split(ARGV[i], arr)
            k = ""
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                k = j SUBSEP k SUBSEP arr[j]
                Tree[k]
            }
            Tree[k] = "$" ARGV[i+1] #=> now can test "if (Tree[k])"
            delete ARGV[i]
            delete ARGV[i+1]
        }
    }
    {
        Key = (int(Key) + 1) SUBSEP Key SUBSEP $1
        if ( Key in Tree ) {
            if (Tree[Key]) {
                print substr(Tree[Key],2)
                Buffer = ""
                Key = ""
            }
            else
                Buffer = Buffer $1 "\n"

        } else {
            print Buffer $1
            Buffer = ""
            Key = ""
        }
    }
    END { if (Buffer != "") printf ("%s", Buffer) }
' - \
    '3 4'        '&'     \
    '6 7 8'      '9 9'   \
    '6 7 9'      '8 8'   \
    '7 10'       '11 12' \
    '0'          ''      \
    '10'         '13 10' \
    '8 9 12 3 5' '#'
```

<sup>**edit:** I realised that the code doesn't backtrack after failing to find a complete match in the B-tree, so it's wrong...</sup>

---

###### How I'm planning to tackle the problem

I'm emulating a [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) with an array and keys in the following format:

- from the middle to the left of the key are the consecutive depths
- from the middle to the right of the key are the consecutive values

When a key exists in `Tree`:

- if it doesn't have an associated value then it's a **node**
- if there's a value then it's a **leaf**

So, for the current input parameters, the content of the `Tree` array will be:

```bash
# from param: "3 4" => "&"
Tree[  1,"",3  ]
Tree[2,1,"",3,4] = "$&"

# from param: "6 7 8" => "9 9"
Tree[    1,"",6    ]
Tree[  2,1,"",6,7  ]
Tree[3,2,1,"",6,7,8] = "$9 9"

# from param: "6 7 9" => "8 8"
Tree[    1,"",6    ]
Tree[  2,1,"",6,7  ]
Tree[3,2,1,"",6,7,9] = "$8 8"

# from param: "7 10" => "11 12"
Tree[  1,"",7   ]
Tree[2,1,"",7,10] = "$11 12"

# from param: "0" => ""
Tree[1,"",0] = "$"

# from param: "10" => "13 10"
Tree[1,"",10] = "$13 10"

# from param: "8 9 12 3 5" => "#"
Tree[        1,"",8         ]
Tree[      2,1,"",8,9       ]
Tree[    3,2,1,"",8,9,12    ]
Tree[  4,3,2,1,"",8,9,12,3  ]
Tree[5,4,3,2,1,"",8,9,12,3,5] = "$#"
```

Comment: You mention space delimted, but your input is delimited by new-lines

Comment: I think the problem is with `9` that is replaced by an empty string. This breaks with your logic, as you check if `Tree[9]` has a value. Since it does not, the logic breaks.

Comment: Are you looking for a fix for your b-tree approach or just a general solution to the problem of doing those replacements?

Comment: @kvantour The real input is `[[:space:]]+` delimited but it's so complicated to do the searches/replacements with it that I simplified  the problem by applying `tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'`

Comment: @EdMorton there's a problem in my code and I didn't identify it yet. If there's a better approach (with `awk`) I would like to know about it. About the tags: `od -A n -t u1 -v 80GB_binary_file | tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' | awk ...`

Comment: @Fravadona : you want it to be replaced with the **`null byte`** itself or just the 4-char `ASCII`  string of `\000`  ??

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto the literal `\000` for now, but the real use will be  to replace a bunch of bytes by an other bunch of bytes, `NUL` byte included

Comment: Got it, so the input is delimited by various types of spaces but you don't want to retain those spaces in the output, you want all output spaces to be newlines only.

Comment: Does the solution need to be with a POSIX awk or could it be gawk-specific? If it has to be POSIX you should mention that in the question. I'm specifically thinking of the fact that with gawk you could set `RS="[[:space:]]+"` and then you wouldn't need the initial `tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'`.

Comment: You say `the input is too big to fit in RAM` - could 1 line of the input be too big to fit in RAM (e.g. if all of the input was a single line)?

Comment: @EdMorton the real target is `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`, but I'm open to different awk solutions, if they can reduce the complexity

Comment: @EdMorton I said that`the input is too big` because the simplest solution for this problem is to reduce the input to a single record with `tr -s '[:space:]' ' '`, but that has the effect of slurping the whole file in RAM

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but there's different numbers of fields on each line of the sample input so if ALL of the input could be on 1 line then you can't use an awk solution that uses the default RS without doing some pre-processing, e.g. with `tr`, so I'm just asking if that's a possibility.

Comment: Can you ever have overlapping/subset requirements like "replace 3,4 with 7" and "replace 3 with 9", or "replace 2,3 with 5" and "replace 3,4 with 7" when the input contains "2,3,4"? If so, how should those be handled - first mapping listed handle first, or longest mapping handled first, or shortest or something else? I assume you don't want recursive mappings to occur, e.g. "replace 3 with 4" and "replace 4 with 9" converting 3 to 9, let us know if that's wrong.

Comment: @EdMorton That's right, recursive mapping isn't supposed to happen. For the ordering of the replacements, ideally it should respect the order of the parameters; for ex. if `2 3 4` and `2 3` were specified is that order then a `2 3 4` in input shall match `2 3 4` (never `2 3`), but if `2 3` was specified before `2 3 4`, then `2 3 4` will never match anything in input

Comment: do you know in advance that there can never be more than `max` number of elements in a sequence? (in the provided sample we see `max == 3` due to `6` `7` `8`)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I agree with Ed, the idea is nice but it has a few shortcomings that can be improved on; I couldn't make it work with `GNU Awk 4.0.2` though

Comment: @markp-fuso No, I don't know how long they will be; they're input parameters

Comment: in the sample inputs all replacements consist of a single token; is it possible that a replacement could consist of multilpe tokens separated by spaces (eg, `10 15`) and if so should the entire replacement be placed on one line of output or should the replacement also be broken up with spaces replaced by `\n`?

Comment: @markp-fuso There will be some replacements with multiple tokens but splitting them isn't needed

Comment: re: the `Tree[]` structure ... would probably help to see more sample inputs that show how 'duplicate' nodes would be handled, eg, `'6 7 8' => '9'` / `'6 7' => 'XXX'` / `'6 7 9' => '10'` (keeping in mind the ordering of these 3 pairs could vary)

Comment: @markp-fuso I don't know how I can handle priorities in the `Tree`, but handling `6 7 8` and `6 7 9` isn't a problem (see the updated question). BTW, I didn't have the time to scrutinise your answer yesterday but it seemed to handle everything nicely so I upvoted it. Was there a problem with it?

Comment: nothing wrong with the logic of the answer but the performance wasn't great when I ramped up the size of `input.txt` so deleted the answer while I was working on a complete rewrite but ... am now sidetracked; I've undeleted the answer for now; if I get the rewrite done I'll update/modify the answer at that time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

- previous answer (see edit revisions) was woefully slow (several minutes) when run against a ramped up input (7K mappings in `map.txt`; 25M tokens
  in `input.txt1`)
- new answer (below) is a complete rewrite and processes the 7K-mappings/25M-tokens in ~45 seconds

---

The main component of this design centers around a tree-like node structure used to manage the series of tokens (lines of input from `map.txt`):

```
tree [ParentNodeNbr] [token] [NodeType] = value
```

Where:

- `ParentNodeNbr == 0` for the `root`
- `token` from `map.txt`
- `NodeType` has one of two values `'node'` or '`leaf'`
- for `NodeType = 'node'` the value stored in the array is a numeric node number (implemented as an counter that's incremented each time a new node is added to the tree); this node number becomes the `ParentNodeNbr` for the next token in the series
- for `NodeType = 'leaf'` this designates the 'end' of a series of tokens (line of input from `map.txt`) and the value stored in the array is the line number (aka `FNR`) from `map.txt`; this line number (`FNR`) is used as an index into a couple other arrays and to determine precendence when an input sequence (from `input.txt`) has multiple matches from `map.txt`
- when processing a series of tokens from a `map.txt` line of input we start at `ParentNodeNbr == 0` looking for a series of matching nodes, adding new nodes as needed

Setup: storing replacements in a comma-delimited file (`map.txt`), and adding one additional line to `input.txt`:

```
$ head map.txt input.txt
==> map.txt <==
2 3 4,X                    # "2 3 4" has precendence over ...
2 3,Y                      # "2 3"
3 4,&
6 7 8,9
9,
0,\000
13 10,10

==> input.txt <==
2 3 4                      # keep eye on "2 3" vs "2 3 4" precendence
112 3
4 6 7
 8  9 12  0  3
4 15   255 13
10 6
7 8 199 9
0 13
```

**NOTE:** here's what `tree[][][]` looks like when populated from `map.txt`:

```
tree [Parent] [Token] [NodeType] = NodeVal

Parent   Token  NodeType   NodeVal     MapTo    ** MapTo only applies to NodeType = leaf
======   =====  ========   =======     =====
     0       0      leaf         6    "\000"
     0       2      node         1
     0       3      node         3
     0       6      node         4
     0       9      leaf         5        ""
     0      13      node         6
     1       3      node         2
     1       3      leaf         1       "Y"
     2       4      leaf         2       "X"
     3       4      leaf         3       "&"
     4       7      node         5
     5       8      leaf         4       "9"
     6      10      leaf         7      "10"
```

One `GNU awk` (for multidimensional arrrays):

```
awk '

function replace(op) {

    while ( ((maxToken - minToken + 1) >= maxlen) || op == "flush" ) {

          NodeNbr=root
          minOrd=maxOrd

          for (j=0 ; j<maxlen; j++) {                             # loop through tokens in buffer[]
              token=buffer[ ((minToken + j - 1) % maxlen) + 1 ]

              # if we find a matching "leaf" node then keep track of the ordering (ie, FNR from map.txt; lower order == higher precedence)

              if ( token in tree [NodeNbr] && "leaf" in tree[NodeNbr][token] )
                 minOrd= ( tree[NodeNbr][token]["leaf"] < minOrd ) ? tree[NodeNbr][token]["leaf"] : minOrd

              # if we find a matching "node" node then grab the next node to compare against the next token from buffer[]

              if ( token in tree[NodeNbr] && "node" in tree[NodeNbr][token] ) {
                 NodeNbr=tree[NodeNbr][token]["node"]
                 continue
              }

              break                                               # if we get here we have a token from buffer[] that does not match any of our replacement mappings so abort checking rest of buffer[]
          }

          if (minOrd < maxOrd) {                                  # if we found at least one complete match (ie, hit a "leaf" node) then ...
             print map[minOrd]                                    # use the associated "ord"er to print the associated replacement string and ...
             minToken=minToken + len[minOrd]                      # update the pointer into the buffer[] array
          }
          else {                                                  # otherwise we did not find a match so ...
             print buffer[ ((minToken - 1) % maxlen) + 1 ]        # print the first token from buffer[] and ...
             minToken++                                           # update the pointer into the buffer[] array
          }

          if (minToken > maxToken)
             break
    }
}

BEGIN   { root=maxNodeNbr=maxToken=0
          minToken=1
          maxOrd=9999999999
        }

FNR==NR { split($0,a,",")

          map[FNR]=a[2]                                           # save replacement string for this input line from map.txt

          n=split(a[1],b)                                         # break our matching pattern into tokens

          len[FNR]=n                                              # make note of number of tokens in this line of input
          maxlen=(n > maxlen) ? n : maxlen                        # keep track of longest series of tokens

          NodeNbr=root                                            # initiate our tree search

          for (i=1 ; i<=n ; i++) {                                # loop through our list of tokens
              token=b[i]

              if (i==n)                                           # if the last token for this line then create a "leaf" node and store the line number (aka "order")
                 tree[NodeNbr][token]["leaf"]=FNR
              else
              if ( tree[NodeNbr][token]["node"] )                 # else if we already have a node at this point in the tree then grab its associated node number for the next level in the tree
                 NodeNbr=tree[NodeNbr][token]["node"]
              else {                                              # else create a new "node" node and populate with the next available node number
                 tree[NodeNbr][token]["node"]=++maxNodeNbr
                 NodeNbr=maxNodeNbr                               # use this as the next level in our tree traversal
              }
          }

          maxrec=FNR                                              # keep track of total number of replacement sets from map.txt (only used if we decide to print the contents of map[] to stdout
          next
        }

FNR==1  {

          # Uncomment following to display the contents of the map[] array:

#          for (i=1;i<=maxrec;i++)
#              print "map:" i ":" map[i] ":"
#
          # Uncomment following to display the contents of the tree[][][] array:

#         fmt="%6s%8s%10s%10s%10s\n"
#         fmt="%6s%8s%10s%10s%10s\n"
#         printf "tree [Parent] [Token] [NodeType]\n\n"
#         printf fmt, "Parent", "Token", "NodeType", "NodeVal", "MapTo"
#         printf fmt, "======", "=====", "========", "=======", "====="
#
#          for (NodeNbr=root ; NodeNbr<=maxNodeNbr ; NodeNbr++)
#              for (token in tree[NodeNbr])
#                  for (NodeType in tree[NodeNbr][token]) {             # ??
#                      NodeVal=tree[NodeNbr][token][NodeType]
#                      printf fmt, NodeNbr, token, NodeType, NodeVal, (NodeType=="leaf") ? "\"" map[NodeVal] "\"" : ""
#                  }
        }

        { for (i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++) {                               # loop through tokens in current line from input.txt
              maxToken++
              buffer[ ((maxToken - 1) % maxlen) + 1 ] = $i
              if ( (maxToken - minToken + 1) >= maxlen )          # if we have a "full" buffer then ...
                  replace()                                       # look for replacement match
          }
        }

END     { replace("flush") }                                      # flush the rest of buffer[]
' map.txt input.txt
```

This generates:

```
X                          # "2 3 4" has precendence over "2 3"
112
&
9

12
\000
&
15
255
10
9
199

\000
13
```

If we switch the first 2 lines of `map.txt` like such:

```
==> map.txt <==
2 3,Y                      # "2 3" has precendence over ...
2 3 4,X                    # "2 3 4"
```

We now generate:

```
Y                          # "2 3" has precendence over "2 3 4" thus ...
4                          # leaving "4" by itself
112
&
9

12
\000
&
15
255
10
9
199

\000
13
```

Comment: Thanks markp-fuso. I couldn't convert it to POSIX `awk` because of the multi-dim arrays so you should specify that it is GNU `awk` specific. BTW, do you have an idea on how to add a priority with my representation of the Tree in my question and answer?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your `tree[]` structure but it seems to me that each time you process a new match-n-replace pair (and create associated entries in `tree[]`) you could add an entry to another array that corresponds with the priority of the match-n-replace pair (eg, `priority[same_index_from_tree]=NR`, or replace `NR` with an incrementing variable, eg, `++c`); during the search/comparison phase you want to find *all* matches in `tree[]` and for each match you compare the associated `priority[]` with the lowest priority seen so far ...

Comment: once you've found all matches you should have the lowest `priority[]` (plus the associated `tree[]` index) at which point you print the associated replacement string (and remove the associated token(s) from the buffer); 'course, if no matches were found then just print the 1st token from the buffer and then remove said token from the buffer

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I'd approach this by figuring out the max number of records that you might need to search in based on the mappings you want, keep a rolling buffer of that number of records, and then do the comparison part on each buffer, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS = "[[:space:]]+"
    map("3,4"   , "&")
    map("6,7,8" , "9")
    map("9"     , "")
    map("0"     , "\\000")
    map("13,10" , "10")
}
{ buf[((NR-1) % maxRecs) + 1] = $0 }
NR >= maxRecs { prt() }
END { prt() }

function prt(   nr,sep,str) {
    for ( nr=NR-maxRecs+1; nr<=NR; nr++ ) {
        str = str sep buf[((nr-1) % maxRecs) + 1]
        sep = ORS
    }

    print ">>>>" ORS str ORS "<<<<"

    # Replace the above with something that loops through the
    # strings you want replaced, e.g.
    #
    # for ( mapNr=1; mapNr<=numMaps; mapNr++ ) {
    #     old = olds[mapNr]
    #     if ( str ~ old ) {    # add something to avoid partial matches
    #         new = news[mapNr]
    #         replace old with new in the output
    #     }
    # }
}

function map(old,new,   numRecs) {
    ++numMaps
    numRecs = gsub(/,/,ORS,old) + 1
    maxRecs = ( numRecs > maxRecs ? numRecs : maxRecs )
    olds[numMaps] = old
    news[numMaps] = new
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
>>>>
112
3
4
<<<<
>>>>
3
4
6
<<<<
>>>>
4
6
7
<<<<
>>>>
6
7
8
<<<<
>>>>
7
8
9
<<<<
>>>>
8
9
12
<<<<
>>>>
9
12
0
<<<<
>>>>
12
0
3
<<<<
>>>>
0
3
4
<<<<
>>>>
3
4
15
<<<<
>>>>
4
15
255
<<<<
>>>>
15
255
13
<<<<
>>>>
255
13
10
<<<<
>>>>
13
10
6
<<<<
>>>>
10
6
7
<<<<
>>>>
6
7
8
<<<<
>>>>
7
8
199
<<<<
>>>>
8
199
9
<<<<
>>>>
199
9
0
<<<<
>>>>
9
0
13
<<<<
>>>>
9
0
13
<<<<
```

The above is just printing the buff-sized strings, the part to be added is replacing the target strings with the new ones in a way that the next target doesn't match the replaced part which is a common problem with, I expect, lots of solutions online so it's left as an exercise.

You'll also need to tweak it to make sure it doesn't revisit lines at the end of the input.

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS, if you don't have GNU awk then just pipe the input from `tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'` as shown in the question.

Comment: Thanks Ed; I ran a few tests and it's around 3x slower than my fixed code. I'm investigating the reason

Comment: You're welcome, I'll definitely be interested in seeing the final product and some speed comparisons!